# Find eigenvalues without filling the matrix

Tags: functions, linear-algebra

Is it possible to find eigenvalues of a matrix without filling it?

The matrix elements are given by a known function `f[p1,p2]`.  This is relevant for a matrix too large to fit in a memory.

Of course, a custom implementation of the Arnoldi algorithm would allow one to do so. I wonder whether it is possible with built-in functions like `Eigenvalues[]` and some clever rules.

Comment: read this http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LinearAlgebraMatrixComputations.html#1833787992

Comment: @molekyla777 Of course I did. It is all about the usual application of Eigenvalues[], which requires the entire matrix be filled. And what if I am able to compute every matrix element needed but do not want to store the entire huge massive in the memory?

Comment: There is no such builtin function that I am aware of.  If your matrix is sparse, you can take advantage of `SparseMatrix`.  You don't have to *fill* the matrix (if it's sparse) but you do need to precompute the nonzero elements to be able to use builtin functions.

Comment: @Szabolcs Oh yes, of this I am aware, and trying to use now, since my matrix is indeed sparse. Thank you! But what if my sparse matrix does not fit the memory? That's the question...